# Using Chakra UI's useClipboard hook

Tags: javascript, chakra-ui

I have multiple input fields populated with data gotten from redux store. I need help to implement a copy to clipboard function for each input field. Tried doing this but no luck:

```js
import { useClipboard } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const { sandboxKey, token } = useSelector((state) => state.apikeys);
  
const { onCopy, value, setValue, hasCopied } = useClipboard("");

return (
 <InputGroup>
   <Input 
     value={token}
     onChange={(e) => {
     setValue(e.target.value);
     }}
     />
   <InputRightElement>
     <Button onClick={onCopy}>
      {hasCopied ? "Copied!" : "Copy"}
     </Button>
   </InputRightElement>
 </InputGroup>
 
 <InputGroup>
   <Input 
     value={prodkey.prodKey}
     onChange={(e) => {
     setValue(e.target.value);
     }}
     />
   <InputRightElement>
     <Button onClick={onCopy}>
      {hasCopied ? "Copied!" : "Copy"}
     </Button>
   </InputRightElement>
 </InputGroup>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the [`useClipboard` hook](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/hooks/use-clipboard) twice for copying from two distinct inputs. In addition, you should pass the value returned by the hook to the Input's value instead of always passing the same value.

```
const tokenCopy = useClipboard(token);
const prodKeyCopy = useClipboard(prodkey.prodKey);
return (
    <>
        <InputGroup>
            <Input 
             value={tokenCopy.value}
             onChange={e => tokenCopy.setValue(e.target.value)}
             />
            <InputRightElement>
             <Button onClick={tokenCopy.onCopy}>
              {tokenCopy.hasCopied ? "Copied!" : "Copy"}
             </Button>
            </InputRightElement>
        </InputGroup>
        <InputGroup>
            <Input 
             value={prodKeyCopy.value}
             onChange={e => prodKeyCopy.setValue(e.target.value)}
             />
            <InputRightElement>
             <Button onClick={prodKeyCopy.onCopy}>
              {prodKeyCopy.hasCopied ? "Copied!" : "Copy"}
             </Button>
            </InputRightElement>
        </InputGroup>
    </>
);
```